# Worldbuilding Podcast #01 - The Pilot (No Pressure)

Tags: discussion, podcast

The Worldbuilding podcast *The Factory Floor* has released its first episode, [available now](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zaofvXNn-1E) for all your nerd needs and subsequent complaints.

Episode 1 has James as host, and sees our esteemed cast talk over the alignment of fictional and not-so-fictional characters, discusses a myriad of worlds, worldbuilding, and does a little fact-checking of Nex Terren.

[Watch (or listen) here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zaofvXNn-1E) - tell us what you think. There'll be a post put up on the [Worldbuilding blog](https://medium.com/universe-factory) shortly.

**Thanks to James, Green, DaaaahWhoosh, Nex and Art for making it all possible.**

[The Factory Floor YouTube Channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCar5xDnyEGKpjpFKxRRoKzw?view_as=public)

Comment: Ugh, so boring. Thumbs down.

Comment: @NexTerren You're just mad about being wrong on the lead paint thing.

Comment: !!! I forgot to see what Art did for that. Edit: ...Nothing? Aw.

Comment: @NexTerren There's an annotation that pops up over the screen if I recall.

Comment: @Nex: watch 01:16:09 onwards.

Comment: I didn't realize I would see 3 guys and a Duck.

Comment: @Skye Hey now.  That's a goose.

Comment: @James  I question my sanity.

Comment: @Skye Welcome to humanity ;)

Comment: Review(All personal opinion): I felt that it was a bit hard to hear Green (I had to put the IPhone volume on full blast to hear it properly) and it didn't feel like DaaaahWoosh was there. It felt like DaaaahWoosh wasn't even in the podcast until James had called him. Maybe it's just me, but I thought it would help if you placed those sound things on the bottom left side of Jame's and Green's side on DaaaahWoosh's side as well so it's more obvious he was talking.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, @Skye - most of those things fall within my domain. The sound we can certainly deal with - I'll just export the tracks at higher volume. I think the issue with DaaaahWhoosh is partly down to the lack of camera feed, though we can't really help that - and I'll look into getting volume indicators.

Comment: Is there an MP3/RSS version of the podcast?

Comment: @billpg not currently no...but that is something we should probably do and make available...we will chat about it

Comment: @James - Please do let us all know when that's available. I listen to podcasts while traveling and YouTube really doesn't fit there.

Comment: @ArtOfCode any chance we can retroactively do what Bill asked for?

Comment: @billpg I can probably get you an MP3 pretty easily. RSS I'd have to look into a bit more.

Comment: So I read this and my first thought was "we have a podcast now?"

Comment: Finally got around to watching it, not bad guys :). It seemed a shame to have one person without a video, it did make them seem less "there". Also I think you might be better off doing more frequent and shorted podcasts. Perhaps record long ones but then split them into half hour chunks for publishing?